# How can I redirect unauthenticated Blazor Azure AD users to a different page than authenticated users?

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm using the Blazor Server templates included with Visual Studio 2019.

In the template application that uses local authentication, When I view the page without being authenticated, the AuthorizeView tags work as expected, and the log in/out buttons on the navbar are displayed dynamically based on these tags. I am able to view the counter and weather forecast pages as a guest.

In the template application that uses Azure AD authentication, whenever I try and view a page without being authenticated, I'm redirected to the Microsoft login prompt. I'm still able to use the AuthorizeView tags to dynamically display components in the navbar, but what I want to be able to do is view the counter and weather forecast pages as a guest without getting redirected.

Is there any way to achieve this? Am I maybe missing something in App.razor?

Edit:

If I log out using the navbar link, and then navigate back with my browser, I can view the pages without authorization. But then when I refresh the page, I get sent back to https://login.microsoftonline.com/. What could be causing this? I want to view an unauthorized home page without getting redirected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour you see is by design.

To change it you can make this change inside Startup.Configure :

```
services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    //options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

(and of course reduce this code to just `services.AddControllersWithViews();` when you want to keep it this way.)

With this change  you will have to block private pages with `@attribute [Authorize]` or with `<AuthorizeView>` and there is no automatic redirect to the login page.

Comment: I feel like there is a bit of a hole in Blazor router/auth functionality. It's common to want most of the app secure, but have one or two pages unsecured for welcome/help pages. Jumping straight to "log in" via B2C is very bad UX. I could make it work for ASP.NET Core MVC using `[AllowAnonymous]`, shame it does not work for Blazor