# How to prevent Blazor with azure ad from redirecting to login page directly after startup

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am testing with Azure AD (**not** B2C) authorization and after registering the application and selecting MS Identity platform as authorization scheme when creating a new Blazor Server project, this all works pretty much out of the box.

Here is the issue: The app redirects the user immediately to the MS login page after accessing the first site. I would normally like to show some content for unauthorized users with a scheme like:

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <p>This can only be seen when logged in!</p>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <p>This can be seen without being logged in.</p>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

I only want to forward the user to the MS login page after pressing the login page (or if the application triggers a redirection, that was consciously programmed by me)

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60233103/how-can-i-redirect-unauthenticated-blazor-azure-ad-users-to-a-different-page-tha) similar question, but the proposed solution

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
}).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();;
```

does not work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer myself, and it seems to be embarrassingly simple.
In `Program.cs` don't set the default policy:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
```

instead use

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
```

directly.